# How do I scrape a password protected site in R?

Tags: r, authentication, screen-scraping

I have read about 7 or 8 SO posts on this exact subject, but a) I still don't know how to login to my target site, and b) I can't see that the SO posts answer my 2 questions below.

Here's my attempt:

```
library(httr)
handle <- handle("http://dominogirl.co.uk/authentication?back=my-account") 
login <- list(email = 'myusername', passwd  = 'mypassword')
response <- POST(handle = handle, body = login)
```

Questions:

1) How can I determine which fields the login form requires? I think the fields are 'email' and 'passwd' from glancing over the source code on the login page, but this approach seems a bit crude - is there a better way to identify the fields that the form requires?

2) How do I know if the login was successful? Is there some response from the web site which tells me this? Or do I just have to start scraping and see what comes back?

Any guidance here is greatly appreciated

Comment: You need to answer first the question of how does the website manage authentication.  Many sites wouldn't allow authentication just via POSTs.  Those that do, you should be able to find out how they authenticate and follow the instructions.  You might need to use an API key or some other method of authenticating.